# multiple view 9-patch sizing issue

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a layout with a root as a custom `RelativeLayout` and within there some arbitrary `Views`. In my code i programmatically add some new `View`s and set a background supplied by the attributes in the `onCreate()` in my custom `RelativeLayout`. I add a nine-patch drawable from xml in my layout xml.

Now up until this point everything works fine when a `View` (in my case a `TextView` with a width of `WRAP_CONTENT`) is added. The problem arises when i try to add a second one which is  shorter then the first one. The background of the first one now all of a sudden starts to match the size of the second one.

I tried mutating the drawable using `mutate()`, but there's no difference, probably because you have to call that when you actually do some operation on the drawable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed reading the drawable id instead of the drawable itself. When inflating my views i set the background with the previously mentioned drawable id and it all works fine.